# Commerce: How can I check order history to see if a product type has been purchased?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

I am building a plugin that grants access to a "hidden" (for lack of better words) entry. if a user has purchased a specific product *type*.

For example, I don't care which piece of clothing the user purchases, just as long as it was of type clothing.

How can I check the users order history to see if they have purchased a qualifying product?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you change your selected answer to mine please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Commerce 1.1.1211 you can do:

```
{% if currentUser %}
{% set order = craft.orders.user(currentUser).hasPurchasables(product.defaultVariant).all() %}
{% if order|length %}
    <strong>I already own this product: </strong> <a href="/shop/customer/order?number={{ order[0].number }}">Order #{{ order[0].shortNumber }}</a>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

First you'll need to grab the user's orders. Then you can check the product type through the purchasable.

Something like this:

```
{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.user(currentUser).find() %}

{% if orders|length %}
    {% for order in orders %}
        {% for lineItem in order.lineItems %}
            {{ lineItem.purchasable.product.typeId }} {# 1 #}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

You can take that a step further by doing something like this:

```
{% set orders = craft.commerce.orders.user(currentUser).find() %}
{% set product = false %} {# set the condition to false by default. #}

{% if orders|length %}
    {% for order in orders %}
        {% for lineItem in order.lineItems if lineItem.purchasable.product.typeId == 1 %}
            {% set product = true %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {# No orders found. #}
{% endif %}

...

{% if product %}
    {# User has purchased product type at some point in time. #}
{% else %}
    {# User has never purchased product type. #}
{% endif %}
```